# Resize all divs with certain class using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some js code that resizes a div id according to window size

```
function resize()
    {
        var heights = window.innerHeight;
        document.getElementById("somediv").style.height = heights + "px";
    }
    resize();
    window.onresize = function() {
        resize();
    };
```

This is great but I want it to resize several divs with the same class. I tried using getElementByClass but that didn't work.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `<div>`'s have the class `somediv` you can do the following

```
function resize()
 {
    var heights = window.innerHeight;
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("somediv");
    for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
       divs[i].style.height = heights + "px";
 }
resize();
window.onresize = resize;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery is very easy:

```
function resize()
    {
        var heights = window.innerHeight;
        $('.common-class').css('height',heights + 'px');
    }
```

But if you want to use pure JavaScript then you need to use loop:

```
var cmn = document.getElementsByClassName('common-class');
for(var i = 0; i < cmn.length; i++) {
    cmn[i].style.height = heights + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `getElementsByClassName()[1]`, like:

```
...
var heights = window.innerHeight;
var divEle = document.getElementsByClassName("some_class");
for(var i = 0; len = divEle.length; i < len; i++) {
    divEle[i].style.height = heights + "px";
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have several elements with the same ID, your HTML is not valid.

You should use Document.getElementsByName()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName

Answer (score 0):

Since all answers are using `getElementsByClassName`, i'm adding that [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) may be a better solution:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.somediv');
```

- it is more adaptable to future changes
- good to learn CSS selectors